# How to clear the cache or do a hard refresh in Safari?

Tags: safari, refresh

I am used to doing this in Windows with FireFox or IE by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Is there a way to do this for Safari on a Mac?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Go to `Safari > Empty Cache`, or hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. To refresh, click the refresh button on the addressbar or press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Another tip. If you want to restore Safari, like completely clear all the caches, or parts of it, go to `Safari > Reset Safari`. I use it usually when I need to clear a lot of memory from Safari, for it will clear the webpage screenshots, the cookies, the favicons, etc.

---

**Edit:** On the latest version of `Empty Cache` isn't on the `Safari` menu any more. It's now on the `Develop` menu. To show the `Develop` menu it, go to `Safari > Preferences...`, click the `Advanced` tab, and check `Show Develop menu in menu bar`. The keyboard shortcut remains unchanged, though.

`Safari > Reset Safari` isn't an option any more. To clear history you can use `History > Clear History...` and to clear cookies/local storage data, go to `Safari > Preferences...`, click the `Privacy` tab, and either click `Remove All Website Data...` or `Details...` to view and remove it for individual sites.

Comment: What can be done on an iPad or iPhone Safari?

Answer (score 52):

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and clicking the Refresh button generally does a full refresh. You can also empty cache with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, and then refresh.

Comment: I appreciate your answer as it solved my issue.

Comment: @NullPointer great to hear it!

Comment: The command sequence for that should be Cmd + Shift + R. As described here: http://dotjay.co.uk/2007/05/hard-refresh-firefox-mac

Comment: I really _need_ this solution to work, but it doesn't. I'm looking at a css file at url ending style.css?ver=1.0  If I view this URL in chrome, or with wget, it's showing the restored version, but safari is refusing to refresh. If I change the URL in any way then it refreshes but that's no use to me. So now I'm left trying to figure out how to backup my saved passwords so I can try the 'Remove All Website Data...' nuclear option. All this so that safari will lose its cache on one poxy little css file. Infuriating!

Comment: While looking into it yesterday I came across a couple of other ideas which I'll stick here: [RichardF suggests](https://twitter.com/richardf/status/808685513469231104) _"open resource (alone) in a new window, shift-cmd-R, then go back to first window and shift-cmd-R"_ .  [Mathias Bynens suggests](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46735/how-do-i-truly-flush-safaris-cache#comment53470_46739) _"focus the Web Developer Tools while performing the keyboard combo"_    I can't confirm whether those would fix it for me, because when I came back after lunch the problem had gone away.

Comment: Just to counter @HarryWood (my sympathies). This does in fact work for at least Safari 11.0.2 at time of writing this. That does not mean your cache, browser, etc. cannot get thoroughly confused/broken (happens eventually in every browser I've ever used), which may well be what Harry has encountered.

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't already, enable developer tools: open settings (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), go to the advanced tab, and check the box that says "Show Develop menu in menu bar."

Empty caches a single time: **Develop > Empty Caches**

Keyboard shortcut to empty caches a single time: **Opt + Cmd + E**

If you want to *disable caching* (for example, if you are developing a website and need to consistently reload changes to files on your site) you can do so: **Develop > Disable Caches**.  Select this option again to reenable caching.

Note: for Safari 11 the disable caching feature was moved to the Network section of the web inspector.  Open the web inspector with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, go to the Network tab, and click the icon on the far right that looks like this:

[image: disable caches button]

Comment: There is no Disable Caches option on safari 11.

Comment: @Noishe this option is still there, but it moved.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Now if only it was available while debugging mobile!

Comment: @Noishe under the Develop menu you should be able to use the options "Enter Responsive Design Mode" and "User Agent" to debug the mobile view of your application.  If you open the web inspector the button should still be there.

Comment: I wish I could trust the idiosyncrasies of individual platforms to an emulated version, but alas, I've been bitten by that before and can not.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

This is the correct answer for people looking for Safari's equivalent for <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in Chrome. This works for both Safari and the Web Inspector when connected to an iPad/iPhone.

Keep in mind this **does not** clear cache, it simply does a "Hard Refresh".

Comment: This is the correct answer. The OP isn't asking for clearing caches, but doing a hard refresh, which is what `Ctrl-F5` does on a Windows browser.

Comment: @cjbarth Seriously. How is it that one has to scroll down so far to find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You must click **References**->**Advanced**->check to **Show develop menu in menu bar**. Later in Inspect Element press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

**Note**: Your mouse must click into the element within "**Elements tab**", then you can press Shift+Cmd+R.

[image]

Comment: It's just **command⌘** + **R** nowadays (Safari 14). The trick being to open the Web Inspector (**option⌥** + **command⌘** + **I**) before triggering a refresh.

Answer (score 3):

[image: On Develop Menu]
If Develop Menu not show in your bar, setting it on *Safari→Preferences→Advanced* and check in "Show Develop menu in menu bar"

Or, you can press <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>  <kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

on Safari version Version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8), it seems to be <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

You can check by 
open up Develop menu on top > look for Empty Caches item on the drop down list > see what the shortcut is.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Tested in Safari Version 12.0.1 (14606.2.104.1.1)

Answer (score -1):

If you are use safari browser in windows, then `ctrl + alt + e` use for empty cache.

Comment: No-one should still be using Safari on Windows. It was last updated in 2012.