# How to 'clear refresh' a page display in web browsers (aka. 'hard refresh', ie. ignoring cache)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

While doing web development I often need to refresh a site I'm building with the cache ignored. What are the best ways to do this?

I used to use the 'Disable cache' option in Firefox's Web Developer Toolbar. However this disables the cache globally, slowing other sites down, and has the following bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643184

I [gather you can do a 'clear refresh' in PC Chrome](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-developer-tools/browse_thread/thread/24654a66030d4ae7?pli=1) with ctrl-F5? Is there an equivalent in Mac Chrome, or Firefox for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox OS X 3 options:

Force Reload Page (override cache)

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Reload button

Edit:

Wikipedia has an overview about how to [bypass the cache on nearly every browser imaginable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBypass_your_cache).

Comment: +1. Just FYI: [for Safari, it’s a bit different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46739/4408).

Comment: Thanks both. I'll accept that assuming it works in the latest version of Firefox 11 - haven't managed to reproduce a caching issue without it to test yet!