# Downloaded MacOS Mojave and now I can't sign into iCloud

Tags: icloud

I recently downloaded MacOS mojave and now I can't sign into my icloud. Following some other threads, I tried to sign out of all icloud apps on my mac, and while it wouldn't let me at first, saying it couldn't connect to the Apple ID server, it eventually worked and my mac successfully signed out of icloud. Anyway, now it won't let me sign in, continually giving me the same message box as before saying it can't connect to the Apple ID server. I've restarted my mac several times in the process, but that didn't help at all. The problem exists across all users and using Safe mode didn't help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you sign in a browser (Safari) at https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin with your AppleID credentials?

Comment: Yes, I can. The problem is not the credentials themselves. Rather my Mac is simply showing that it can’t connect to the Apple ID server itself.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is your internet connection ok?

Comment: Yes, it sure is. I also just realized though that safari is not responsive whatsoever either. Normally I use Chrome and so I did not even notice till now. I can sign into icloud.com though so the problem is not with my credentials.

Comment: If Safari is not responsive, holding shift  will do a hard refresh and can bring it out of some problems. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46735/how-do-i-truly-flush-safaris-cache/46739#46739 If doing so in Safe mode also gives problems, one can reinstall os.