# Safari - Reload Page from Origin, does what exactly?

Tags: macos, safari

If you hold `cmd` and click `View` -> `Reload Page From Origin` what does that do exactly and how does it differ from a standard reload?

I'm **guessing** it reloads the current page **without** using cache? But i'm not sure. I hope some one can confirm this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loads the page and any same-domain resources requested by the page without using the cache. Resources located on other domains may still use the cache. You can completely bypass the cache [using the Network tab of the Web Inspector](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299693/how-to-disable-all-caches-in-safari-11) as just [⌥⌘R is insufficient](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284445/how-to-do-a-complete-refresh-in-safari-10-1-1-on-macos-sierra).