# Turn off "this web page is using too much battery" on safari

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra

[image]Safari prompts "this web page is using too much battery" and restarts the web pages. Most of these pages are gmail, youtube, etc.

How to turn this feature off on macOS 10.13.6?

EDIT1: Memory - 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3. Processor - 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5

EDIT2: While opening YouTube, it always says "the page was reloaded due to some error"

EDIT3: Just one extension - Grammarly

EDIT4: Another problem with YouTube (see image) (private window does not open YouTube at all) (I was currently at 3% battery at that time)

Comment: I don’t see that message at all for a month or more. What os are you running and have you looked at a JavaScript blocker?

Comment: macOS 10.13.6. I am under the understanding that it is a Safari feature.

Comment: I have never seen this message and I use Safari on a daily basis. Is there way to reliably reproduce the issue?

Comment: @n1000 I see that on matlab online,  google drive if I upload/ download a lot of things, reddit after scrolling a long long way down that it starts glitching. Unfortunately, I cannot think of a way to make this come up without loading a tab with a lot of content.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii How much RAM do you guys have installed?

Comment: @n1000 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, processor: 1.8 GHz Intel Core i5 on MacBook Air. Don't know about OP. but I think it won't matter. this is enough to start with. For me, this is rare. But as OP is really troubled(bounty) by it, Harshal, please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: As I said, I have never seen this message. Same OS, MBP mid2015, 16GB.

Comment: @n1000 16 GB must be really helpful in this case though. Lowers the percentage occupancy by a tab in total RAM. I am on 10.14.5. However, Safari doesn't *restart* the page though. Only a warning. It would be a disaster for unsaved work.

Comment: I have an 8GB Ram and 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5. It usually happens when I keep gmail open for a long time.

Comment: Please check the post for edits.

Comment: I can at least recommend clearing cache if you can tolerate loosing some log-ins. Also, try and check the behaviour in Safe mode of safari itself (hold down shift key and click on Safari icon in dock. ) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12049/how-to-clear-the-cache-or-do-a-hard-refresh-in-safari How many extensions do you have?

Comment: Just one - grammarly

Comment: "too much battery" implies processor usage is high.  I suggest you run activity monitor to verify that Safari is using a lot of the processors. As a test, turn off grammarly.

Comment: @historystamp, trying that and posting the results shortly

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions listed on https://blog.fonepaw.com/this-webpage-is-using-significant-memory-energy.html? Though nothing special, they seem to be general measures to reduce processor usage, possibly solving your issue.

Here's a discussion thread on Apple's forum related to your issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8353302.

Comment: I faced that youtube issue too. Turned off extensions and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for the problem that is causing this trouble rather than hacking the Safari to stop showing you notifications. If it's upto to kill the process, preventing notifications will not stop it.

Here are few troubleshooting tips.

1) Check your disk space where your OS is installed. Free if needed (Swap memory reason)

2) Check your HDD & Battery health. You can get few freeware utilities.

3) Check temperature of your system. It often crash apps or even restarts the devices.

4) Clear the browser cache folder from base. See [this Post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8330774) for details.

5) Reset SMC

```
Press Shift + Control + Option + Power button at the same time. 
Release all keys and the power button at the same time.
```

6) Reset NVRAM

```
Shut down your Mac.
Press the power button.
Before the grey screen appears, press the Command, Option, P, and R keys at the same time.
Hold the keys until your computer restarts and you hear the startup sound a second time. ...
Release the keys.
```

7) Check for Safari and iTunes Updates.

If none of the above works and your hardware has no issues, than probably it's time to fresh install (upgrade) your OS.

Comment: Could you also add extension-disable troubleshoot too? Browser seems to be at fault.